# How to select max of count in PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql, group-by

I have table in PostgreSQL with the following schema:

```
Category    |   Type 
------------+---------
A           |   0 
C           |   11 
B           |   5 
D           |   1 
D           |   0 
F           |   2   
E           |   11 
E           |   9 
.           |   . 
.           |   .
```

How can I select category wise maximum occurrence of type? The following give me all:

```
SELECT 
    category, 
    type, 
    COUNT(*)
FROM 
    table
GROUP BY 
    category, 
    type
ORDER BY 
    category, 
    count 
    DESC
```

My expected result is something like this:

> Cat     |Type |Count
>   --------+-------+------
>
> A     |0      |5
>
> B     |5      |30
>
> C     |2      |20
>
> D     |3      |10

That is the type with max occurrence in each category with count of that type.

Comment: Put column name in `count(col_name)`

Comment: Can you please include the expected result in your question as well?

Answer (score 8):

You can use the following query:

```
SELECT category, type, cnt
FROM (
   SELECT category, type, cnt,
          RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY category 
                       ORDER BY cnt DESC) AS rn
   FROM (
      SELECT category, type, COUNT(type) AS cnt
      FROM mytable
      GROUP BY category, type ) t
) s
WHERE s.rn = 1
```

The above query uses your own query as posted in the OP and applies `RANK()` windowed function to it. Using `RANK()` we can specify all records coming from the initial query having the greatest `COUNT(type)` value.

*Note:* If there are more than one types having the maximum number of occurrences for a specific category, then *all* of them will be returned by the above query, as a consequence of using `RANK`.

[**Demo here**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/8e308/19)

Answer (score 2):

If I understand correctly, you can use window functions:

```
SELECT category, type, cnt
FROM (SELECT category, type, COUNT(*) as cnt,
             ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY type ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC) as seqnum
      FROM table
      GROUP BY category, type
     ) ct
WHERE seqnum = 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT 
    category, 
    type, 
    COUNT(*)
FROM 
    table
GROUP BY 
    category, 
    type
HAVING 
    COUNT(*) = (SELECT MAX(C) FROM (SELECT COUNT(*) AS C FROM A GROUP BY A) AS Q)
```

EDITED:
I apologize to readers,

```
COUNT(*) = (SELECT MAX(COUNT(*)) FROM table GROUP BY category,type)
```

is the ORACLE version, postgresql version is:

```
COUNT(*) = (SELECT MAX(C) FROM (SELECT COUNT(*) AS C FROM A GROUP BY A) AS Q)
```

Comment: This gives **aggregate function calls cannot be nested** for MAX(COUNT(*))

Answer (score -1):

SELECT category , MAX (Occurence) 
FROM (SELECT t.category as category , Count(*) AS Occurence FROM table t);

Answer (score -2):

```
SELECT 
    category, 
    type, 
    COUNT(*) AS count
FROM 
    table
GROUP BY 
    category, 
    type
ORDER BY 
    category ASC
```